# how to fetch data from database in four different divs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i want to fetch out the 4 different id's rows from the database. and display in four divs. each div contains a character base unique id. i am doing this to write same query again and again. i want to do with less query.
my code is given below.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from acms_pages where id = 40");
$sql = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
           <li id="pgAbout">
         <section class="content">
            <div class="one_half_last"><?php echo $sql['text'];  ?></div>
            </section>
        </li>

<section class="content">
            <?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from acms_pages where id = 41");
$sql1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
        <li id="pgPortfolio">
            <div class="fullwidth"><?php echo $sql1['text'];  ?></div>
           </section>
        </li>

<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from acms_pages where id = 42");
$sql2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
        <li id="pgServices">
                 <section class="content">                
                <div class="one_half_last"><?php echo $sql2['text'];  ?></div>
            </section>
        </li>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from acms_pages where id = 43");
$sql3 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
        <li id="pgPrices">
             <section class="content">
                <div class="one_half"><?php echo $sql3['text'];  ?></div>
             </section>
        </li>
```

Comment: You should be using the new mysqli: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Code optimization question - should probably be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This probably belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com, but the general approach would be to rewrite your query as a single query, with the where clause including all four conditions OR'd together.

Then you can access each row independently and render the divs.

Comment: i know it. but what source code could be apply on all divs to display content.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (I think...) you can just use OR in your query:

```
mysql_query("select * from acms_pages where id = 40 OR id = 41 OR id = 42");
```

However, you should be using the mysqli instead:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "mydb");
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "select * from acms_pages where id = 40 OR id = 41 OR id = 42")) 
{
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf ("%s", $row[0]); //first column value here
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: please also define $variable which are placed on all four divs. just like '<?php echo $sql1['text'];  ?>'.

Comment: see the code for `mysqli_fetch_row` you can store the values there and echo them in your `<div>`'s accordingly

Comment: If order is important, you may need to also write a loop for the id's in the order you want, and then check `$row[0]['id']` before generating the output

Comment: thanks a lot @peacemaker sir. but i have little bit confusion in this.

Comment: thanks a lot @ernie sir. could you please give me full coding for it.